# How does China reduce the amount of leaks?

Tags: china, government

It seems like leaks are prevalent in public administrations in Western democracies such as the United States, which explains why Wikileaks became such a big problem for the U.S. However, strangely enough, leaks don't seem to happen often given that rarely confidential papers get leaked through organization such as Wikileaks and Bellingcat. How does China achieve to do this?

Comment: Shoots the leakers in the back yard in the presence of their colleagues, it seems. At least when they leak to the CIA. Anyhow, I somewhat question the premise given the recent (and rather massive) leaks [on Xianjing](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/11/16/world/asia/china-xinjiang-documents.html) https://www.dw.com/en/china-leaked-xinjiang-files-likely-accurate-experts-say/a-61919739 or Covid https://thehill.com/policy/international/528055-leaked-documents-show-china-mishandled-early-covid-19-pandemic-report/

Comment: OTOH not hiring Ron Paul & Ayn Rand (libertarian) fans seems would have prevented the biggest leaks in the US https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2022/06/13/the-surreal-case-of-a-cia-hackers-revenge

Comment: It is fairly clear from context, but to be clear (particularly for non-native English speakers), this question is using the term "leaks" in the sense of unauthorized disclosure of confidential information by people who have insider knowledge of that information.

Comment: Being written in Chinese probably helps *a lot* to reduce the number of "points of contact" between Chinese leakers and Western leak organizations. Like how the UK, Canada, Australia and NZ copied a lot of stupid USA politics around the end of the Trump era, but France and Germany and Switzerland and Italy did a lot less so, because their average citizens don't speak English and whatever they did get was filtered through someone translating it first.